# Select column max solo selecciona hasta el 9

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una consulta en mi base de datos

```sql
SELECT MAX(CUENTA)cuenta FROM cat_cuentas_contables WHERE CUENTA like '1.1.02' + '%'
```

al cual le sumo 1.

Para eso paso esa consulta a una variable y extraigo los últimos 2 dígitos para sumarle 1, se los borro y le concateno la suma anterior.

Pero como la columna **CUENTA** es un *VARCHAR(20)* solo  me trae hasta el **09**, *"1.1.02.00.0009"* y ya no me trae el *"1.1.02.00.00010"*.

¿Hay alguna forma de traer los números que terminan en 0 como 10, 20, 30, etc?

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu problema exactamente, ese `LIKE` traerá también los valores como `1.1.02.00.00010`. Por cierto, no hace falta concatenar el LIKE, puedes ponerlo así: `like '1.1.02%'`

Comment: El problema está en el ´MAX´: el campo "Cuenta" es un String, así que se ordena como *String*, esto es: "1.1.02.00.0009" > "1.1.02.00.00010"; Si esos son números de cuenta contable creo que deberían tener la misma longidud, o sea, el segundo código debería ser "1.1.02.00.0010" (2 ceros antes del 10)

Comment: A. Cedano gracias por responder, también creía lo mismo y todo iba bien hasta el insert del registro `1.1.02.00.00010` pero cuando vuelvo a consultar con el select max me sigue trayendo el 09, no se que podría estar mal, tenías razón con el like no hace falta concatenar el %

Comment: Roimer. muchas gracias, eso no lo estaba tomando en cuenta, con tu observación se solucionó  el problema, muchas gracias